# Invoke webservice using jaxws when the wsdl has more than one service

Tags: java, jax-ws, web-services

I'm trying to get hold of the FindService on [this](http://service.mappoint.net/standard-30/mappoint.wsdl) wsdl using jaxws.
I generated the classes just fine using wsimport.

But when i do:

```
FindService findService = new FindService();
```

i get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: {http://s.mappoint.net/mappoint-30/}FindService is not a valid service. Valid services are: {http://s.mappoint.net/mappoint-30/}CommonService
```

So, it seems that jaxws is only finding CommonService in the wsdl which is the first one declared in it.
Any idea how i can use the FindService ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a JAX-WS bug.

You can make a local copy of the WSDL, modify it so that FindService is the first service definition declared, and run wsimport against it. That worked for me.